# Difference between /usr/lib and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folders

Tags: ubuntu

I'm not very familiar with the linux root folders.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. What is the difference between the two folders `/usr/lib` and `usr/lib/x68_64-linux-gnu`.

I ask this since my `boost` .so files are of different versions in the two folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is the [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) folder for libraries built for 64-bit x86 on Linux using the GNU C library. `/usr/lib` is the historical folder for libraries built for the system; you’ll still find libraries there because quite a few packages don’t follow the multiarch spec.

The Boost packages in Ubuntu ship their libraries in the multiarch folder, so the libraries in `/usr/lib` are presumably from a source other than Ubuntu, or from an older version of the package that’s still installed.

Comment: Thanks! Is it safe for me to remove the boost related .so files in the `usr/lib/x68_64-linux-gnu` folder, and copy the boost related .so files from `/usr/lib` to that folder?

Comment: No, don’t remove the files from `/usr/lib/x68_64-linux-gnu`. Are the files in `/usr/lib` newer?

Comment: Yes, in the `/usr/lib` folder, I have boost 1.72 version, while in the `/usr/lib/x68_64-linux-gnu` folder, I have 1.65 version. I am running into dependency conflicts for certain package installations because of this.

Comment: You shouldn’t manually remove packaged files; `/usr` (apart from `/usr/local`) is managed only by the package manager. I suggest you ask a new question to explain the dependency conflicts you’re running into, you’ll get more useful answers that way.